# ¿De dónde viene la segunda acepción de "pomada"?

Tags: coloquialismos

Según el DLE, **pomada** tiene como segunda acepción:

> 2. f. coloq. Círculo de personas que por su prestigio o influencia ocupan una posición social o profesional privilegiada. *Eran los triunfadores, la gente que estaba en la pomada.*

que no parece muy relacionada con la primera acepción convencional:

> 1. f. Mixtura de una sustancia grasa y otros ingredientes, que se emplea como cosmético o medicamento.

¿Cómo surgió esa acepción?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola!

Por [aquí](https://infulas.blogspot.com/2006/06/el-origen-de-la-expresin-estar-en-la.html) he encontrado una explicación que tiene origen bélico. Sin entrar en demasiado detalle (en el enlace tienes más información), el origen viene de que los soldados más exitosos (los que más enemigos abatían) tenían preferencia a la hora de obtener la "pomada" para curar sus heridas, de ahí la segunda acepción.

Comment: No tiene sentido porque no son "prestigiosos" los soldados. Solo los ricos se echevan una pomada.

Comment: De alguna forma deberían curarse las heridas los soldados. Y a la hora de elegir ante la ausencia de pomada, la dabana a quienes iban a rendir mejor, es decir, los que más enemigos abatían.

Comment: No me has entendido. Los hombres ricos se echaban pomada, por eso la pomada está asociada con "una  una posición social o profesional privilegiada".

Answer (score 0):

Sinónimos de **Pomada**: **Crema**, ungüento, cosmético, potingue, untura, untadura.

La expresión "**Estar en la pomada**" como "*Círculo de personas que por su prestigio o influencia ocupan una posición social o profesional privilegiada*." no aparecerá de forma directa, sino que la locución se derivaría de otra anterior de origen francés, "***crème de la crème***", literalmente "*la crema de la crema*", con el significado de "élite, la mejor flor de la sociedad", documentada desde 1848 y aplicado también a lo más distinguido de un grupo social cualquiera. Ejem. "*La crema de la intelectualidad*". Está expresión, "***crème de la crème***", a su vez estaría basada en el modismo, "**la flor y la nata**", aunque perdiendo el sentido irónico de aquella, pero con igual significado, "*ser lo más selecto dentro de un grupo, lo mejor*" y que tiene origen en otra aún más temprana, pues en Roma ya se hablaba de "flos como cremor", "lactis flos; cremor", (flor de la leche),  "vini flos" (flor del vino), "salis flos" (flor de la sal)...

Donde "**Flos**", *es lo más puro y acendrado de cualquier cosa* y "**Crĕmor** , oris" *como tipo de crema, referido al jugo espeso obtenido de sustancias animales o vegetales, caldo espeso, papilla, etc.*, Cato, R. R. 86; Platón pers. 1, 3, 15; Cels. 3, 7, 2; 6, 6, 26; ov. Fac M. 95.

Así este ungüento o "**crema**", se ha considerado desde siempre el elemento más puro de la leche y que más sustancia tenía. La "**crema**" es la que esta situada en la parte más alta de la leche, sustancia a la que también llamamos "**nata**", por tanto, **crema** y **nata** en este contexto **son sinónimos**, (*en Iberoamérica, lo que se conoce por “crema de leche”, en España se denomina “nata líquida”*. ).

En este sentido, se establece un paralelismo entre la **crema** o **nata**, que es esencia y sustancia, y que se encuentra en la parte más elevada de la leche, y así decir, "**la flor y la nata de la sociedad**" se refiere estar en lo más alto de la misma, como la "crema o nata lo están en la leche", es decir, se alude a lo más puro de la sociedad y dentro de está, a lo más fino y selecto de la misma, lo mejor de lo mejor.

De esta manera llegamos a la expresión "**Estar en la pomada**", que es como decir "**"Estar", en el sentido de encontrarse o pertenecer a la "Crema", pues "**Pomada es sinónimo de Crema**", "**Estar en la Crema**", "**Estar en la Pomada**" es decir, ser o pertenecer a lo mejor, a lo más selecto, en este caso, de la sociedad**", aunque también se puede especificar, como hemos manifestado antes de forma especial, "Estar en la Pomada (Crema) de la Intelectualidad, del Deporte, de la Política, de los Directores de Cine...", pues, estás palabras "***crema, nata y pomada***" son sinónimos.

**Crema** también aparece en las siguientes entradas:

afeite - betún - cosmético - élite - flan - **flor** - grasa - **leche** - loción - **nata** -
natillas - pasta - **pomada** - puré - unto...

Comment: Hola 今夜九, espero que te encuentres bien, quizás no me exprese bien, lo siento, intentaba solo explicar el recorrido de distintas variantes que simbolizan lo mismo. De forma coloquial siempre hemos dicho, por ejemplo,  échame un poco de untura, échame un poco de crema o échame un poco de pomada. Coge del cajón la crema, coge del cajón la pomada...ve a comprar...de tal manera que "crema" y "pomada" se utilizan de forma indistinta para expresar una misma cosa. Por otro lado, la crema es la nata de la leche. Si eres tan amable y tomas un poco de tiempo veras que lo que te digo es cierto. Gracias.

Comment: Ejemplo - PREGUNTA: Hola solo una consulta pequeña. La nata es lo mismo que la crema de leche o es otra cosa. .https://www.laverdad.es/gastronomia/preguntas-respuestas/hola-una-consulta-pequena-nata-lo-mismo-crema-leche-o-otra-cosa--20070130000000-nt.html Gracias de nuevo por tu comentario y por ayudarme a intentar ser más claro o especifico con el estudio realizado. Un saludo.

Comment: 今夜九 aquí tienes otro ejemplo - Crema de leche. La crema, nata o gordura de leche es una sustancia de consistencia grasa y tonalidad blanca o amarillenta dulce que se encuentra de forma emulsionada en la leche recién ordeñada o cruda... https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crema_de_leche

Comment: ¡ Gracias a ti!